# TypeError when writing data to Influx with None values using Python's aioinflux user defined schema

Tags: python, influxdb, python-dataclasses, aioinflux

So I have a schema that I defined and use with `aioinflux` library to write data from Python to `InfluxDB`:

```
from datetime import datetime
from aioinflux import lineprotocol, TIMEDT, TAG, FLOAT, MEASUREMENT, INT
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional


@lineprotocol(
    schema=dict(
        timestamp=TIMEDT,
        measurement=MEASUREMENT,
        object_id=INT,
        dt=TAG,
        weight=FLOAT,
        width=FLOAT,
        size=FLOAT,
        risk=TAG,
        confidence=FLOAT,
    )
)
@dataclass
class CbdrDebugPoint:
    timestamp: datetime
    object_id: int
    dt: str
    weight: float
    size: Optional[float]
    width: Optional[float]
    risk: Optional[str]
    confidence: Optional[float]
    measurement: str = "my_table_name"
```

but if any of my `Optional` fields get value equal to `None` the writing to influx fails with the following error:

```
TypeError("Invalid variable type: value should be str, int or float, got None")
```

but for sure it is possible to write `null` values to influx, so any idea why does this error appear?

Comment: You can't pass null via http api, you will have to skip the null fields some how if the library you are using doesn't support this.

Answer (score 0):

So after digging in the [aioinflux package](https://aioinflux.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), it seems that is has this werid behavior:

- If you try to write the data using the dictionary format it does accept `None` in the dictionary and it simply omits them from writing them to influx so you get the desired behavior
  -If you use the use defined schema with the `dataclass` it does not have the same behavior, isntead it tries to actually write None to `Influx` and it fails

So a way around it was for me to keep the user defined schema as short of documentation where the `dataclass` easily describes the model and it can be easily maintained but then I just added a `to_dict` method to make the dictionary that `aioinflux` expects as shown below:

```
from datetime import datetime
from aioinflux import lineprotocol, TIMEDT, TAG, FLOAT, MEASUREMENT, INT
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional


@lineprotocol(
    schema=dict(
        timestamp=TIMEDT,
        measurement=MEASUREMENT,
        object_id=INT,
        dt=TAG,
        weight=FLOAT,
        width=FLOAT,
        size=FLOAT,
        risk=TAG,
        confidence=FLOAT,
    )
)
@dataclass
class CbdrDebugPoint:
    timestamp: datetime
    object_id: int
    dt: str
    weight: float
    size: Optional[float]
    width: Optional[float]
    risk: Optional[str]
    confidence: Optional[float]
    measurement: str = "my_table_name"

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            "measurement": "my_table_name",
            "fields": {
                "object_id": self.object_id,
                "weight": self.weight,
                "size": self.size,
                "width": self.width,
                "confidence": self.confidence,
            },
            "tags": {
                "dt": self.dt,
                "risk": self.risk,
            },
            "time": self.timestamp,
        }
```

and then before writing to `Influx` I produce this dictionary. It is a hack but given that the library does not support writing `None` for user defined schema it is an acceptable solution.